# Reducing sentences with which/who in the middle

Tags: reduced-relative-clauses

The following two exercises from the TOEFL longman seems to be tricky. Which one is correct and which one is incorrect.

> ______ The food placing on the picnic table attracted a large number of flies
>
> ______ Dissatisfied with the service at the restaurant, the meal really was not enjoyable.

It is stated in the book that `if there is no be-verb, it is possible to reduce the sentence with _ing`. Also, it is possible to `move the reduced sentence to the beginning of the sentence and drop the which/who/...`. Please see below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm confused... neither of those sample sentences contain which or who.

Answer (score 1):

The second example makes no sense.

"Dissatisfied with the service at the restaurant, the meal really was not enjoyable."

The only subject in the sentence is 'the meal'. The only meaning can be that the meal was dissatisfied.

I suspect this problem is what you are being asked to address, nothing to do with the sort of reduction/inversion seen in:

- 'The diners, [who were] unsatisfied with the service, did not enjoy the meal.'

versus

- 'Unsatisfied with the service, the diners did not enjoy the meal.'

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence seems to follow the pattern you are looking for

> The food *which was placed* on the picnic table attracted a large number of flies.
>   The food *placed* on the picnic table attracted a large number of flies.
>   *Placing* the food on the picnic table attracted a large number of flies.

however the original sentence

> The food *placing* on the picnic table attracted a large number of flies.

is incorrect and barely understandable.

In your second sentence

> Dissatisfied with the service at the restaurant, the meal really was not enjoyable.

does not seem to follow the pattern you are looking for since the adjective clause doesn't modify "meal", but it is correct and understandable.

Comment: regarding the second sentence,  the book says it is INCORRECT and says (illogical reduction)... I don't understand that

Comment: Also, regarding the first sentence, I say that it is similar to the rule that has been described (using ing). So, if there is another rule, please let me know